# Assigning a tab pane to an excessive button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've created a navigation bar (a toggleable one with pills) and different tab panes to assign the nav-pills to them (using Bootstrap5). I want to add a button in one of the tab panes (Home tab) and assign another tab pane (About tab) to it. the nav-pills work fine with their tabs but the excessive button doesn't seem to work. how can I fix that?
the nav-pills

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

the tab panes and the button

```
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <div class="d-grid">
    <a class="btn btn-block" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.